# SaltStack: salt.states.file wildcards in ID declaration or name?

Tags: wildcard, salt-stack

It looks like `salt.states.file` doesn't like wildcards in the ID or name. I'm trying to manage permissions of a consistent subdirectory within a variable parent, e.g., I want to manage permissions on 'poo'. 'poo' is consistent (with lots of fiber),  but its parent directory can be variable:

```
/massive/poo
/lotso/poo
/runny/poo
/Manny Pacquiao vs Floyd Mayweather/poo
```

You get the idea.
It's okay for the parent to have the default permissions, but I want to manage the subdirectory. Something that

```
chmod 775 /*/poo
```

would take care of.

Is there a way to do this with salt states?

Answer (score 0):

You can run specify a cmd.run for this.

```
Test_command:
    cmd.run:
        - name: chmod 755 /*/poo
        - unless: (insert some logic here)
```

I include the insert statement because it's "best" to always check if the command needs to run unless you want it to run EVERY TIME, unless you want slow performance...

Hope this helps.